# What exactly is a "declaración jurada"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, lenguaje-jurídico

Reading an article in El Pais I see a headline

> Madrid pedirá una declaración jurada a las personas que estén en la calle donde expliquen su destino

Looking in the DLE for enlightenment I find only one definition for *jurado* as an adjective

> 1. adj. Que ha prestado juramento al encargarse del desempeño de su función u oficio.

and searching for *jurar* I find three definitions which might be relevant

> 1. tr. Afirmar o negar algo, poniendo por testigo a Dios, o en sí mismo o en sus criaturas.
> 2. tr. Reconocer solemnemente, y con juramento de fidelidad y obediencia, la soberanía de un príncipe.
> 3. tr. Someterse solemnemente y con igual juramento a los preceptos constitucionales de un país, estatutos de las órdenes religiosas, graves deberes de determinados cargos

So the first of these is about what I would call in English swearing an oath, and the other two look like swearing allegiance.

As I understand it though the citizens will be obliged to have with them a piece of paper which they have filled out to show to police or other authorities if stopped. I cannot really see any way they can swear on it though, they are hardly being encouraged to find a notary for that purpose.

So my question is: what does jurado mean here?

Comment: sworn statement, or a statement made under oath.  Means they can be criminally prosecuted if found to be lying (cf. perjury)

Comment: @user0721090601 It wouldn't be perjury according to the Spanish penal code, as only witnesses before a court can commit perjury. It can't be punished as "falsedad documental", either, as lying in a document ("falsedad ideológica") is only a crime when a civil servant or authority does it. I don't think it can possibly be a crime at all, since that would be akin to forcing self-incrimination.

Comment: "declaración jurada" can be translated as "sworn statement" or "affidavit". The person need not swear before a notary or a judicial officer for the statement to be valid and enforceable.

Comment: @OnlyThenDidIReckonMyCurse I didn't say it was perjury. (*cf* means *compare to*)

Comment: @user0721090601 You did say it could be criminally prosecuted. I said it couldn't.

Comment: @OnlyThenDidIReckonMyCurse «Las sanciones por incumplir las restricciones de movilidad impuestas en el marco del estado de alarma oscilan entre los 100 y los 600.000 euros, si bien, merced a esta pretensión del Consistorio madrileño, determinadas conductas pueden acabar, además, ante el juez por un **delito de falsedad**, al margen de la multa por desobediencia que tipifica la Ley de Seguridad Ciudadana»

Comment: @user0721090601 Avisa cuando El País se llame "Código Penal" y se publique en el BOE.

Comment: @OnlyThenDidIReckonMyCurse El artículo que cité es el mismísimo de *El País*, que cita el Ayuntamiento de Madrid.  Pero vamos, si dudas ese periódico, helo aquí: ***Ley Orgánica 10/1995, de 23 de noviembre, del Código Penal*, Título XVIII, Capítulo II, Sección 2.ª, Artículo 395**, publicado en el BOE núm. 281, de 24 de noviembre de 1995.

Comment: @user0721090601 Sé que es de El País, por eso lo he dicho. El artículo 395 me dices. "El que, para perjudicar a otro, cometiere en documento privado alguna de las falsedades previstas en los tres primeros números del apartado 1 del artículo 390". Falta el dolo de "perjudicar a otro". Y, si te hubieras molestado en leer, verías que "los tres primeros números" del art. 390.1 no incluyen "Faltando a la verdad en la narración de los hechos", que sería el cuarto número. Hablar de "gilipolleces" en vez de reconocer que no tienes razón es pueril. Por mi parte, se ha terminado esta conversación.

Comment: @user0721090601 el [artículo 395](https://www.boe.es/buscar/pdf/1995/BOE-A-1995-25444-consolidado.pdf) no menciona el concepto "declaración jurada" en ningún sitio. Habla de falsificar documentos en general, que es delito si perjudica a otro.  El delito de perjurio no existe en España. Y no, no son gilipolleces.

Answer (score 3):

> ### Diccionario del español jurídico
>
> #### [declaración jurada](https://dej.rae.es/lema/declaraci%C3%B3n-jurada)
>
> Sublema de [declaración](https://dej.rae.es/lema/declaraci%C3%B3n)
>
> > *Gral.* Manifestación personal verbal o escrita., donde se asegura la veracidad de lo declarado bajo juramento ante autoridades administrativas o judiciales. Se presume como cierto lo que se declara mientras no se acredite lo contrario.

Comment: just add a little bit more, if you don't tell the truth in a 'declaración jurada' is a crime called 'perjurio', it is considered as if you lied in court, it is about that severity

Answer (score 2):

A **Declaración jurada** corresponds in English to an **affidavit**.

I have translated the definition given at Wikipedia in Spanish:

> It is a written or verbal manifestation whose veracity is guaranteed
>   by an oath before a judicial or administrative authority. This causes
>   the content of the statement to be taken as true until proven
>   otherwise.

You can read the definition in English at Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affidavit

So jurada means "something attested by a jury or someone with the power of law to do it".

Answer (score 1):

It is here what is called in French *une déclaration sur l'honneur*.

It is a dated and signed statement in which you undertake to tell the truth. Unlike an affidavit, there is no authority backing it but if a police officer discover you lied, you can be in trouble for breaking the *estado de alarma* rules:

> Artículo 20. Régimen sancionador.
>   El incumplimiento o la resistencia a las órdenes de las autoridades competentes en el estado de alarma será sancionado con arreglo a las leyes, en los términos establecidos en el artículo diez de la Ley Orgánica 4/1981, de 1 de junio.